# UWP xaml logic:

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

can someone explain to me what this code in a App.xaml does, especially the logic:AppDataModel part. AppDataModel is Class in the Project.

```
<Application.Resources>

        <logic:AppDataModel
            x:Key="TheViewModel" />

        <x:String
            x:Key="AppName">Master app</x:String>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: It's creating instances of `AppDataModel` and `String` as [resources in a resource dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references). They'll be used elsewhere, referenced by their keys. There's no logic there, just creating objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This markup, when parsed, creates two entries in the `Application.Resources` dictionary. They key `"TheViewModel"` is tied to a new instance of `AppDataModel` and the key `"AppName"` is tied to a `string` initialized to `"Mater app"`.

To go beyond your question, the *reason* you do this in XAML is to co-locate (keep together) your UI code and some instance data, loosely speaking. The biggest example is wanting your UI to always have a particular view model that it binds to. This can be achieved, as I assume from the markup you posted, like you're doing. Creating a view model object in the resources for a given control, window, or app and then assigning it using `{StaticResource TheViewModel}` will keep you from having to muddy up your code-behind or your view model with binding code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

These xaml lines add items to the Resources dictionary of the current application:

```
Application.Current.Resources["TheViewModel"] = new logic.AppDataModel();
Application.Current.Resources["AppName"] = "Master app";
```